# Diff mudando linhas

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, diff

Estou comparando dois arquivos, que são atualizados diariamente, com o comando `diff -y` afim de obter dois resultados:

O primeiro são as linhas que foram modificadas de um dia para o outro:

```
grupoAzul;Gabriel;04-maçãs;02-limões       |    grupoAzul;Gabriel;05-maçãs;02-limões
grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões             grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões
```

Para isso, uso o comando `diff -y arquivoAntigo.csv arquivoNovo.csv | grep -e "|"`

O segundo são as linhas novas:

```
grupoAzul;Gabriel;04-maçãs;02-limões       |    grupoAzul;Gabriel;05-maçãs;02-limões
grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões             grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões
                                           >    grupoAzul;Kratos;04-maçãs;00-limões
```

Para esse resultado o comando `diff -y arquivoAntigo.csv arquivoNovo.csv | grep -e">"` é utilizado.

Explicado isso, vamos ao erro

Quando aparece uma linha nova em cima da linha modificada, o diff 'empurra' a linha modificada para baixo e considera ela como a linha nova e a que era para ser a linha nova ele considera como linha modificada.

```
grupoAzul;Gabriel;04-maçãs;02-limões       |    grupoAzul;Kratos;04-maçãs;00-limões
                                           >    grupoAzul;Gabriel;05-maçãs;02-limões
grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões             grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões
```

Esses acontecimentos são, de fato, raros de acontecerem mas quando acontecem tenho mais de uma linha prejudicada.

O que causa esse bug e como posso resolve-lo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é causado porque os registros iguais não aparecem na mesma linha em ambos os arquivos. O diff compara arquivos **linha a linha**. No exemplo de problema que você mostrou, a linha 2 do arquivo da esquerda é diferente da linha 2 do arquivo da direita, logo deve ser mesmo marcado com ">".

Para evitar essa circunstância, utilize `sort` para que todos os registros coincidentes apareçam na mesma linha em ambos os arquivos:

```
$ diff -y <(sort arquivoAntigo.csv) <(sort arquivoNovo.csv)
                                          <
grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões         grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões
grupoAzul;Gabriel;04-maçãs;02-limões      | grupoAzul;Gabriel;05-maçãs;02-limões
                                          > grupoAzul;Kratos;04-maçãs;00-limões
```

Entretanto, como pode ver, o espaço em branco no primeiro arquivo obtém primeiro lugar no algoritmo do `sort`, então sugiro também remover as linhas em branco utilizando o `sed`:

```
$ diff -y <(sort arquivoAntigo.csv | sed '/^\s*$/d') <(sort arquivoNovo.csv | sed '/^\s*$/d')
grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões         grupoAzul;Amanda;03-maçãs;05-limões
grupoAzul;Gabriel;04-maçãs;02-limões      | grupoAzul;Gabriel;05-maçãs;02-limões
                                          > grupoAzul;Kratos;04-maçãs;00-limões
```

A expressão regular utilizada no `sed` (`/^\s*$/`) busca todas as linhas que contêm zero ou mais caracteres em branco, como espaços e tabulações, e as exclui com o comando `d`.

Em tempo, a notação `<( ... )`, no `bash` serve para que o comando encerrado entre os parênteses seja executado previamente em uma *subshell*. Portanto, ao executar o `diff` acima, os `sort ... | sed ...` são executados e retornam arquivos temporários já tratados para comparação via `diff`.

Para ver funcionando online no tutorialspoint, com a ressalva de que parece não ser possível criar arquivos por lá, então tive que usar variáveis para "simulá-los":  http://tpcg.io/aO9pny

Comment: O número da mesa foi apenas no exemplo.. Vou editar a pergunta para deixar mais clara.

Comment: Independente do conteúdo, o `sort` por padrão classifica os arquivos alfabeticamente. Você tentou aplicar a minha sugestão? Qual foi o resultado?

Comment: Apliquei sim, mas não tive resultados. Ele continua dizendo que a linha nova é a modificada.

Comment: @GabrielHardoim talvez as linhas em branco do seu `arquivoAntigo` contenham tabulações, e na minha resposta anterior o comando `sed` só contemplava o uso de espaços. Alterei meus arquivos de teste para os dados que você mostrou ao editar a pergunta, testei agora com tabbulações e continua funcionando por aqui.  Pode testar de novo, com o comando que alterei na edição?

Comment: Ainda não funcionou aqui :\ . O `arquivoAntigo` não tem espaços em branco. O `diff` "cria" uma linha em branco quando tem uma linha nova no `arquivoNovo`. Tem alguma maneira de falar pro `diff` exibir as linhas novas no final??

Comment: O diff "cria" a linha 2 em branco porque essa é uma diferença legítima: a linha 2 do primeiro arquivo é diferente da linha 2 do segundo arquivo. Por isso a necessidade de `sort`. Para ter os `>` no final do output, use um `| sort -k2 -n` no final do seu comando, isso classifica pela segunda coluna (a que contem `|` e `>`) em ordem numérica. Aparentemente sinais de maior e menor têm um "número" mais alto do que o *pipe*...

Comment: Vi que você aceitou a resposta =). Deu certo? Incluí um exemplo no tutorialspoint:  http://tpcg.io/aO9pny

Comment: Aqui infelizmente não funcionou, mas marquei como certa porq pode ajudar alguém e vc se disponibilizou para me explicar :D